# Multiple DataTable with the same columns in Visual C#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, schema

I wish to create an array of `DataTables` with the same columns. Is there a way to set the schema of all the `DataTables` in one shot instead of running through each `DataTable` and add the columns?

Comment: I think it is possible to do that by cloning the `DataTable` once you have initialized the schema: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this without a loop. Even if there was a method like `DataSet.CloneManyTables` it would use a loop for you. A LINQ solution would also use a loop. So use following:

You can use `DataTable.Clone`, for example with 100 clone tables:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    DataTable tClone = tSource.Clone(); // tSource is your source-table
    tClone.TableName = $"{tClone.TableName}_{i + 1}";
    ds.Tables.Add(tClone);  // ds is your DataSet
}
```

The columns can have the same names but the table-name must be unique.

Comment: See... That's the problem I'm trying to avoid: **for loop**

Comment: @Pikachu620: what makes you think that there was anything in the world that works without a loop when you want to change multiple things? Even if there was a method `DataSet.CreateCloneTables` it would need a loop which you just didn't see.

Comment: @Pikachu620 AKA abstraction.